# When I include the images below, the H2 will not go to the next line. If I remove the img lines, the H2 will go to the next line

Tags: html

When I include the images below, the H2 will not go to the next line.  If I remove the img lines, the H2 will go to the next line.  Help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sample sports photo blog</title>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="kids_sports_photo_site.css">

  </head>
  <body>

<h1>Documenting Sports</h1>

    <h2>Baseball</h2>

    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/3_JwPJwq6CI">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/3k_FcShH0jY">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/f0aE-bu7sco">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/oXQIXgnlW0c">



    <h2>Basketball</h2>



    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please tell which <h2> ?

Comment: The second H2 - I think it is because I have the float there.  I am trying to re-write with flex.